# How to get folder names of list in Sharepoint using javascript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

For the sharepoint requests i am using sharepoint library https://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/. I am struggling to get folder names of the list. And also how to get folder names within a sub folder in list?
If i try to make request on list, i am getting only data about files inside folders. But what if i have folders without files, i can not get the names of that folders.

```
$SP().list("TestList").get().then(function(data) {console.log(data) });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample demo script(check FSObjType if you want to distinguish folder/file):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sharepointplus/browser/sharepointplus.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getFolderAndFilesInFolder() {
            // if you want to list only the files visible into a folder for a Document Library
            $SP().list("MyDoc2").get({
                fields: "BaseName,FileRef,FSObjType", // "BaseName" is the name of the file/folder; "FileRef" is the full path of the file/folder; "FSObjType" is 0 for a file and 1 for a folder (you need to apply $SP().cleanResult()), "File_x0020_Size" the filesize in bytes
                folderOptions: {
                    path: "folder",
                    show: "FilesAndFolders_InFolder"
                }
            }).then(function (items) {
                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    console.log(items[i].getAttribute("FileRef"));
                    console.log(items[i].getAttribute("FileLeafRef"));
                    //console.log(items[i].getAttribute("FSObjType"));
                }
            })
        }
    </script>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" onclick="getFolderAndFilesInFolder()" value="button" />
```

[setup.folderOptions.show="FilesAndFolders_InFolder"] Four values: "FilesOnly_Recursive" that lists all the files recursively from the provided path (and its children); "FilesAndFolders_Recursive" that lists all the files and folders recursively from the provided path (and its children); "FilesOnly_InFolder" that lists all the files from the provided path; "FilesAndFolders_InFolder" that lists all the files and folders from the provided path